# Why I can't return a generic Map?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Updates: I asked a stupid question, I mixed B is subtype of A, then `Map<String, B>` is subtype of `Map<String, A>` as well which is obviously incorrect.

public interface A {
            ....
        }

```
public class B implements A {
    ....
}
```

Now I have this class.

```
Class abstract ABC {
    public abstract Map<String, A> execute();
}


Class XYZ {
    private ABC abc;
    public Map<String, A> doSomeWork(){
       return abc.execute()
    }
}
```

Then

```
Class DEF extends ABC {
   @Override 
   public Map<String, B> execute(){
     ....
   }
}

Class Main {

....
     XYZ xyz = new XYZ();
     DEF def = new DEF();
     xyz.setABC(def);

     Map<String, B> map = xyz.doSomeWork(); //incompatible type error here

....
}
```

Is that the way I'm using generic map totally wrong? what I want is **doSomeWork** method can return different types of map accordingly, I've tried to change the return type to  `Map<String, ? extends A>` which doesn't work either.

I may not clarify the problem, I've updated the missing details.

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: _"...can return different types of map accordingly"_  according to what exactly?

Comment: pls post you stacktraces oder javac errors

Comment: @Carcigenicate incompatible type

Comment: I don't understand the confusion. Why do you think  a value of type `Map<String, A>` can be assigned to a variable of type `Map<String, B>`?

Comment: @JornVernee Ok this `doSomeWork` method contains a composition abstract class, this abstract class will actually return the map, for different implementations it will generate different map.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis because A is the interface, and B is the implementation, just like if I declare a `Map<String, A> map = new HashMap<>()...`, I then can put both `B` and `C` into this map which `B` and `C` are all implementations of `A`.

Comment: Even though `B` is a subtype of `A`, neither of `Map<String, B>`  and `Map<String, A>` is a subtype of the other. See for example [Generics, Inheritance, and Subtypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html).

Comment: @OleV.V. Ok... I think got the point, so if a method was declared to return A, but in fact when it was invoked, it returned B, then in that case it won't complain incompatible type, right?

Comment: That is correct, @Neeson.Z.

Comment: This is in the Java Tutorial, which I commend to your attention. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/subtype.html

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have an additional `class C implement A`.

`public Map<String, A> doSomeWork()` would allow you to return a map that contains any value that implements `A`, i.e. a bunch of `B` instances as well as `C` instance.

Were you allowed to do `Map<String, B> map = doSomeWork();` you'd operate on the assumption that all values are `B` instances which could not be true and thus you'd be in for a nasty surprise. Since the compiler doesn't want you to be surprised this way it complains/warns/refuses to compile right from the start.

And why doesn't `Map<String, ? extends A> doSomeWork()` work? That signature would allow you to return a `Map<String, A>` or a `Map<String, C>` and I hope you can see how assigning both to `Map<String, B>` would break your code.

So what could you do?

- Work under the assumption that `doSomeWork()` returns a map of any value type that implements `A` and just use `Map<String, A> map = doSomeWork()`.
- Tell the method what it should return, e.g. by passing the value type you expect, something like `doSomeWork( B.class )`.

The method could then look like this:

```
public <T extends A> Map<String, T> doSomeWork( Class<T> valueType ){
   ....
}

Map<String, B> map = doSomeWork( B.class );
Map<String, C> anotherMap = doSomeWork( C.class );
```

Answer (score 1):

If the return type of `execute` changes based on the implementation of `ABC`, you could make `ABC` generic:

```
abstract class ABC<T extends A> {
    public abstract Map<String, T> execute();
}

class XYZ<T extends A> {
    private ABC<T> abc;
    public Map<String, T> doSomeWork(){
       return abc.execute();
    }
}

class DEF extends ABC<B> {
    @Override 
    public Map<String, B> execute(){
        ....
    }
}
```

Then:

```
XYZ<B> xyz = new XYZ<>();
DEF def = new DEF();
xyz.setABC(def);

Map<String, B> map = xyz.doSomeWork();
```